# node-typescript application docker command error

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, dockerfile, package.json

I have created a node application using typescript.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node -r ts-node/register index.ts",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.3",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Currently, I have used following docker file for running my application

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
EXPOSE 1234
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

I want to run my application using node command instead of npm

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
EXPOSE 1234
CMD ["node", "-r", "ts-node/register", "index.ts"]
```

But it throws an error like this

```
'egister", "index.ts"]' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ts-node is not registered in the WORKDIR environment, you need to add the relative path.

```sh
CMD ["node", "-r", "./node_modules/ts-node/register", "index.ts"]
```

If you want to run other packages, you need to register the path like this

```
# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```